# SQLite Migration in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, ormlite

I am using ORMLite with Android and I have an entity that has two String attributes (each one being stored in database), and for the migration my entity has changed and the 2 fields have been merged in a List. How can I handle this migration?

Entity before migration :

```
@DatabaseTable
public class MyEntity
{
    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    private int id;
    @DatabaseField
    private String att1;
    @DatabaseField
    private String att2;
}
```

Entity after migration :

```
@DatabaseTable
public class MyEntity
{
    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    private int id;
    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.SERIALIZABLE)
    private ArrayList<String> list;
}
```

I have looked to the structure of the database, before migration att1 and att2 are VARCHAR and after migration list is of type BLOB. I am using a class that extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper for the migration, but I don't know how to pass the values of att1 and att2, in list column in the new migrated database.

Answer (score 0):

> ... the migration my entity has changed and the 2 fields have been merged in a List. How can I handle this migration?

Wow this is going to be hard to do.  You are going to have to read in each of the entities, create the `list` field from `att1` and `att2` and then call `dao.update(...)` to save each entity with the list BLOB field.

Something like:

```
 for (MyEntity entity : dao.queryForAll()) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    if (add1 != null) {
        list.add(add1);
    }
    if (add2 != null) {
        list.add(add2);
    }
    entity.setList(list);
    dao.update(entity);
 }
```

Comment: thanx for your answer. I finally changed my `private ArrayList<String> list;
` into `String list`, like that list is stored in the database as a VARCHAR and finally for migration I concatenate att1 and att2 separated by a comma.